# Running Fortran on Xcode

Tags: xcode4.3, fortran90

I am trying to run sample Fortran code on Xcode 4.3 using a 64-bit compiler and it will not build correctly. The main problem is that despite my best efforts, I cannot get the separate .f90 files to interact with each other, thus code like

> USE ElementModule, ONLY : ElementType

will not work. Does anybody have any answers regarding how to get the separate .f90 files to read each other. I'm aware you have to include specific modules, but my search hasn't given me any straight answers regarding what those specific modules are.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when F90 code compiles, it generates 2 files: an object file and a mod file.  When compiling subsequent modules, the mod files are used for the USE statements.

If you have circular dependency, then you have to build two or more times.  Best to avoid circular dependency if you can avoid it.

The mod files are normally picked up by the same directive that tells the compiler where the include files are.